# Throw exception from flow at corda enterprise cause "Create property Serializer for private property 'errorIdentifier'"

Tags: corda

Now I'm using Corda 3.2 enterprise and 3.3 opensource with same source code but separate compiler (Enterprise I have developer pack).
Then this error only happen in enterprise version.

In Corda opensource API got flowException from cordapp in normally, but in enterprise will got this warning

```
[WARN ] 2019-01-25T08:34:04,789Z [rpc-server-sender] amqp.PropertySerializer.<init> - Create property Serializer for private property 'errorIdentifier' not exposed by a getter on class 'class net.corda.nodeapi.exceptions.InternalNodeException'
        NOTE: This behaviour will be deprecated at some point in the future and a getter required {}
```

Then API side will got this error

```
2019-01-25 07:36:25,972 WARN org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver [requestId:644cae25-d937-426f-a5ac-9bb9ee61b175] [http-nio-8080-exec-9] Failure in @ExceptionHandler public final org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<th.co.jventures.ddlp.cls.apis.core.dto.ErrorDetail> th.co.jventures.ddlp.cls.apis.advice.ApiErrorHandler.handleAllExceptions(java.lang.Exception,org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest)
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not parse 'Accept' header [/]: Invalid mime type "/": does not contain subtype after '/'
        at org.springframework.web.accept.HeaderContentNegotiationStrategy.resolveMediaTypes(HeaderContentNegotiationStrategy.java:59) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager.resolveMediaTypes(ContentNegotiationManager.java:124) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.getAcceptableMediaTypes(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:390) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:228) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:223) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:82) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:119) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveHandlerMethodException(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:412) [spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.doResolveException(AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.java:61) [spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:136) [spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.resolveException(HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.java:80) [spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1297) [spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1109) [spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1055) [spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) [spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) [spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908) [spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) [spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:461) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:394) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:253) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:175) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:791) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_201]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_201]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_201]
2019-01-25 07:36:25,973 WARN org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver [requestId:644cae25-d937-426f-a5ac-9bb9ee61b175] [http-nio-8080-exec-9] Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not parse 'Accept' header [/]: Invalid mime type "/": does not contain subtype after '/']
2019-01-25 08:34:04,864 ERROR th.co.jventures.ddlp.cls.apis.advice.ApiErrorHandler [requestId:5c60a133-b57c-4eb2-aa1d-bc689b3188ab] [http-nio-8080-exec-4] java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: net.corda.nodeapi.exceptions.InternalNodeException: Something went wrong within the Corda node.
th.co.jventures.ddlp.cls.apis.exception.CordAppException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: net.corda.nodeapi.exceptions.InternalNodeException: Something went wrong within the Corda node.
        at th.co.jventures.ddlp.cls.apis.service.cordapp.CustomerCordappClientService.issue(CustomerCordappClientService.java:119) ~[classes!/:?]
        at th.co.jventures.ddlp.cls.apis.api.CustomerApiHandler.issue(CustomerApiHandler.java:67) ~[classes!/:?]
        at th.co.jventures.ddlp.cls.apis.api.CustomerApi.issue(CustomerApi.java:39) ~[classes!/:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038) [spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) [spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) [spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908) [spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) [spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90) [spring-boot-actuator-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) [spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:117) [spring-boot-actuator-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:106) [spring-boot-actuator-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:791) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_201]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_201]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_201]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: net.corda.nodeapi.exceptions.InternalNodeException: Something went wrong within the Corda node.
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1895) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
        at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImpl.get(CordaFutureImpl.kt) ~[corda-core-3.2.jar!/:?]
        at th.co.jventures.ddlp.cls.apis.service.cordapp.CustomerCordappClientService.issue(CustomerCordappClientService.java:117) ~[classes!/:?]
```

I expect the same result as in opensource version that API will got flowException as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Corda Enterprise 3.2 and Corda OS 3.3 have the same API but the implementations are slightly different. Thus it is completely possible to see the warning on one version, but not on the other.

Comment: Then why in enterprise version API got InternalNodeException instead of FlowException and how to fix it?

Comment: The warning is irrelevant here I think. Is there any difference between the code you're running for the OS and ENT versions, especially in terms of the Spring webserver?

Comment: I use same source code but use developer pack for compile in enterprise version for enterprise node